# How to create a subset of geoJson file from existing file

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I have a geoJSON file as below:

```
    var geoJSON=    
    {

    "type":"FeatureCollection",

    "features": [                                             
        {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.463303,36.447488],[102.514114,36.439755]]},"properties": {"id":"01","points":9}},
        {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.593765,36.414341],[102.634964,36.402183]]},"properties": {"id":"02","points":8}},
        {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.880783,36.485038],[102.882156,36.561187]]},"properties":{"id":"03","points":10}}

........
and so on
                ]};
```

From this I want to create a variable filtered_geoJSON where only points >=9 are available like below:

```
var filtered_geoJSON=    
        {

    "type":"FeatureCollection",

    "features": [                                             
        {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.463303,36.447488],[102.514114,36.439755]]},"properties": {"id":"01","points":9}},
        {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.880783,36.485038],[102.882156,36.561187]]},"properties":{"id":"03","points":10}}

........
and so on
                ]};
```

Because each time I update the points of each Line String like

```
  geoJSON['features'][i]['properties']['points']=data[i].points;
```

So from this I want to create the filtered_geoJSON  variable each time and pass it to the

```
L.geoJson(filtered_geoJSON, {
                     style: style,
                     onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);
```

So that I only draw the points which are having points >=9.

So I tried with

```
var top_geoJSON={"type":"FeatureCollection","features": []};
            var c=0;
            for (i = 0; i<40000; i++) { 


                if(geoJSON['features'][i]['properties']['score']!=data[i].points){
                      links['features'][i]['properties']['score']=data[i].score;
                }

                if(geoJSON['features'][i]['properties']['points']>9){
                    filtered_geoJSON[c]=geoJSON['features'][i];
                     c++;
                }
```

The filtered_geoJSON is there but not plotting the lines in the map.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean your `points` values are _dynamically_ changing, and you want the map to show / hide your features accordingly?

Comment: Yes exactly.My geoJSON variable updates all the LineString's points dynamically.From that I would like to show only the Line Strings which are having points above 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`filter`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-filter) option on the Leaflet `L.geoJSON` factory, that you can use to feed your entire `geoJSON` data and have Leaflet keep only the ones that meet your specified criteria (i.e. `feature.properties.points >= 9` in your case).

When you *re-build* your `filtered_geoJSON` variable after updating your `points`, you have to build a new `L.geoJSON` out of it before you get something on your map.

Furthermore, even by changing the `geoJSON` data directly, Leaflet will not evaluate it again through the `filter`, so if some features go below 9, or some new ones go above, this will *not* be automatically reflected on the map.

The most simple solution would be to remove your previously created `L.geoJSON` layer group, and build a new one with your updated `geoJSON` data (and the same filter), so that Leaflet re-evaluates your features again.

A slightly more complex solution would be to iterate through the `L.geoJSON` layer group child layers directly (instead of your raw `geoJSON` data), typically using [`eachLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup-eachlayer), update their `feature.properties.points` there and determine whether it should now be hidden or shown back. You would need to create your `L.geoJSON` layer group initially without any filter, and manually add the child layers to the map / remove them from map. Of course you can also use an intermediate `L.layerGroup`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the filter option.it worked like a charm.